# Heremaps Infobubble CSS does not change

Tags: javascript, css, angular, heremaps

so I looked up every possible solution for changing the CSS style of the infoBubble for heremaps. I work with Angular v8 and thus far only setting the css of the Data has worked for me, but that does not influence the color of the marker.

```
const marker = new H.map.Marker(position);
marker.setData("<div style='width: 100px'>Hello world!</div>");

marker.addEventListener("tap", event => {const b = new H.ui.InfoBubble(event.target.getPosition(), {content: event.target. getData()}); this.ui.addBubble(b);}, false);

this.map.addObject(marker);
```

This css code did not work for me:

```
background-color: yellow;
height: 275px;
}
```

Anyone know as to why it is not working?